# The predict_proba() function of MLPClassifier from sklearn outputs the total possibility is not equal to one

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I used MLPClassifier from sklearn to build a neural network to predict the result of horse racing. 
However, sometimes, when I used the predict_proba() function to predict the winning possibility of each horse, I found that the total possibility was not equal to 1. Sometimes, it might be 0.8xx or 1.2xxx or 1.1xxx, etc. The worst cases could be 2.5xx or 0.3xxx, etc.

No matter how I tuned the model, it would still happen in some predictions.  Also, I did the MinMaxScaler before input the data to the model.

```
rdx = rdx.fillna(value=-999) #-999 means missing data
x = np.array(rdx) #rdx is the feature of data 
y = np.array(rdy) #rdy is the label of data

# Scale Feature
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(x)
x = scaler.transform(x)

# Build network
mlp =  MLPClassifier( activation='relu',alpha=1e-4,hidden_layer_sizes=(20,20), random_state=1,max_iter=1000,verbose=10,learning_rate_init=.1)
mlp.fit(x, y)
```

Features (rdx):

[image: feature]

Labels (rdy):

[image: label]

Result:
[image: Result]
In the each red color box, it is the possibility of all horses in each race. But it is not equal to one after summation. Sometimes, it would be worse such as 3.5 or 0.5, etc.

2 Records of Data:
[image]

What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the problem. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It seems like for each horse you have a separate row/sample which tells based on the features your model predicts which horse will win. Then, for each horse you will get a probability which will tell you what's the chance they will win. Here, they might or might not add to one. Again, this is based on my understanding of the problem. Please provide more info to understand what you are really trying to do

Comment: @JayantSahewal No, all horses in a same race will be in one row. I added the image of my data and posted the all code except the prediction part. Hope you can understanding what i'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: I think it may not be a round-up problem because sometimes the sum will be more than 2 in the worst cases, not just like 1.0xxx or 1.1xxxx. This problem is bothering me. I can't solve it for long time.

Comment: can you post some data?

Comment: @makis OK, I posted the 2 records of my data. As the data is too much, it is so difficult to post all data here. I just showed the record no.1000 and no.1001.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is the way you have structured your labels. You are checking for each horse, what's the probability that the horse will win. These will not need to sum to 1.

Take a look at the below example:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_mnist_filters.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neural-networks-plot-mnist-filters-py

Shape of y_train and y_test is (60000,) and (40000,) is respectively.

But, if you change y_train and y_test to one hot encoded vector (like you have in your data) and then then train a new MLP model on the transformed labels, then you will see that you will get probabilities which will not sum to 1.

I have modified the example referenced in the above link to show what I am trying to say:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Load data from https://www.openml.org/d/554
X, y = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, return_X_y=True)
X = X / 255.

# rescale the data, use the traditional train/test split
X_train, X_test = X[:60000], X[60000:]
y_train, y_test = y[:60000], y[60000:]

# mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100), max_iter=400, alpha=1e-4,
#                     solver='sgd', verbose=10, tol=1e-4, random_state=1)
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,), max_iter=10, alpha=1e-4,
                    solver='sgd', verbose=None, tol=1e-4, random_state=1,
                    learning_rate_init=.1)

mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(y_train.shape)
print(mlp.predict_proba(X_test[:10]).sum(axis=1))

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')

enc.fit(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))

y_train_transformed = enc.transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
y_test_transformed = enc.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()

# mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100), max_iter=400, alpha=1e-4,
#                     solver='sgd', verbose=10, tol=1e-4, random_state=1)
mlp_new = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,), max_iter=10, alpha=1e-4,
                    solver='sgd', verbose=None, tol=1e-4, random_state=1,
                    learning_rate_init=.1)

mlp_new.fit(X_train, y_train_transformed)

print(y_train_transformed.shape)
print(mlp_new.predict_proba(X_test[:10]).sum(axis=1))
```

Comment: No. I have already changed my label to one hot encoding, see the labels photo.

Comment: That's what I am saying if the labels are one hot encoded then it's not a guarantee that the sum of the probabilities will be 1. Each probability tells you the probability of that horse winning the race. It's not conditional on anything else. So, you can't sum them up. You can try converting your label to depict the horse number that won the race. So, for example if the first horse won the race then instead of having 1,0,0,.. you have 1 and if the second horse won the race then instead of having 0,1,0.. you have 2 in the label

Comment: I think this will article will give you a sense of what I am saying - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html. In multi-class, the classes are mutually exclusive while in multi-label they are not. In your case, since only horse will win the race, you should (and probably want) to structure your problem as multi-class classification (not as multi-label). Your label data should be of shape (n, ) where n is number of samples in your dataset and each label will simply tell which horse won the race. I have other suggestions but they do not pertain to the question at hand.

Comment: oic, it means that the MLPClassifier will automatically use one hot encoding and softmax output if I just have 1,2,3...8,9 in the label. If I do the extra one hot encoding, it will think I am doing multi-label so it will automatically choose the sigmoid output for me. Is that right?

Comment: I hit enter before I add more context. In multi-label classification, for each label, you have a separate node for output. And, for each output it will use a sigmoid transformation to convert into respective probability for that label. While in multi-class, you have a single node for the final output. So, yes, in multi-class, it uses softmax to convert the scores for each label into respective probabilities. This is for the neural network architectures in general. Not sure about the specific implementation of mlpclassifier()